# Decryption in java (caesarCipher) wrong result

Tags: java, encryption

I have written simple Caesar ciper algorithm, encrypting works perfectly, but when I want to decrypt word, I am getting wrong result. For example "PQRO" with key 15, should be "ABCZ", but I'm getting
"ABCB".

```
public static void decrypt(String text, int k) {
    char[] tAlf = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char[] tChar = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < tChar.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tAlf.length; j++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == tAlf[j]) {
                System.out.print(tAlf[(Math.abs(j-k)) % 26]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like algorithm can't get backward in alphabet to 'Z'.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: abs( max25 - anythingGreater0 ) % 26 can't never be 25 (Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to understand the math operations.

First of all, `%` is not the modulo operation, it is the remainder operation, which means that the result may be negative.

`abs` will create a positive value out of a negative value. But that's not the same as counteracting the problem with the negative value, as it would map e.g. -1 to 1 instead of 25.

So what you can do is to create an actual modulo operation. In Java that is:

```
int mod(int x, int n) {
    return ((x % n) + n) % n;
}
```

which should fix your problem.

---

As for debugging, you should always start by moving things into smaller pieces. Bring `Math.abs(j-k)) % 26` out of the array indexation and assign it to e.g. an integer `newIndex` variable, so you can actually see the intermediate results. Even better: try and create separate methods such as `int charToIndex(char c)` and `char indexToChar(int i)` so you can test them separately.